# OpenMP application on fortran find best thread

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

For example, I have kmeans code

```
program read_from_file
  use functions_module
  !$ use omp_lib
  character(len=2) :: c2
  integer :: i, j, k, l, c, d
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: r, centroid, new_centro, converge
  real, dimension(:), allocatable :: cost
  integer,dimension(:),allocatable  :: indices,distancereg,cluster
  integer :: ios_read = 0
  integer :: n = 0
  integer :: omega, tid, n_threads
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: comparison_value

  print *, 'which data index?'
  read*, idx

  write(c2, '(i2.2)') idx
  
   open(unit=99, file='datatest1.dat', iostat=ios_read)
  if (ios_read /= 0) then
    print *, "kmeans_data_distrib_"//c2//"_small.dat could not be opened"
    ! print
  end if

  !find the maximum lines
  do
    read(99, *, iostat=ios_read) i, x, y

    if (ios_read > 0) then
      print *, "something is wrong"
      stop
    else if (ios_read < 0) then
      print *, "end of file reached"
      exit
    else
      n = n+1
    end if
  end do

  rewind(99)
!do i=1,n
  open(unit=98, file='rawdata.dat')
  allocate(r(2, n))
  do i = 1,n
    read(99, *, iostat=ios_read) j, x, y

    r(1, j) = x
    r(2, j) = y
    write(98, *) x, y
  end do

  close(99)   ! close kmeans
  close(98)   ! close rawdatai
  print*, 'put k'
  read*, k
allocate (comparison_value(2,k))
comparison_value = 0.02
** do l=1,10
call centroid_inits(r, n, k, centroid)
      
  call min_distance(r, n, k, centroid, distance,indices,distancereg)
  call new_centroid(r,n,k,centroid,indices,new_centro,omega)
     call costfunction(r,n,k,distancereg,indices,new_centro,cluster,cost)

  end do

      
  open(unit=99,file="kmeans3_test.dat")
  do i = 1, n
     write(99,"(2es14.5,i4)") r(:,i),indices(i)
enddo
  close(99)


Contains
  subroutine centroid_inits(r,n,k,centroid)
      real,dimension (:,:),intent(in),allocatable :: r
      real,dimension (:,:),intent(out),allocatable:: centroid
      real,dimension(k),allocatable::xc(:) ,yc(:)
      integer,intent(in) :: n,k
      integer :: i
      real :: maks_x,maks_y,min_x,min_y
      allocate(centroid(2, k))
      allocate(xc(k))
      allocate(yc(k))

      maks_x = maxval(r(1,:))
      maks_y = maxval(r(2,:))
      min_x = minval(r(1,:))
      min_y = minval(r(2,:))
     ! print *, min_x, maks_x, min_y, maks_y
     
      do i = 1,k
        xc (i) = min_x + (maks_x - min_x) * fib_rnd()
        yc (i) = min_y + (maks_y - min_y) * fib_rnd()
        centroid (1,i) = xc(i)
        centroid (2,i) = yc(i)
      end do
    
      do i = 1,k
        print *, centroid(:,i)
      end do
    end subroutine centroid_inits

  subroutine min_distance(r,n,k,centroid,distance,indices,distancereg)
        integer, intent(out):: n,k
        real,dimension(:,:),intent(in),allocatable::centroid
        real,dimension(:,:),intent(in),allocatable::r
integer,dimension(:),intent(out),allocatable::indices,distancereg
        real ::d_min
        integer::y,i_min,j,i
        integer,parameter :: data_dim=2
        allocate (indices(n))
        allocate (distancereg(k))
        !cost=0.d0
       
        do j=1,n

           i_min = -1
           d_min=1.d6
         ! !$ OMP DO
           do i=1,k
              distance=0.d0
              distancereg(i)=0.d0
              do y=1,data_dim
                 distance = distance+abs(r(y,j)-centroid(y,i))
                 distancereg(i)=distancereg(i)+abs(r(y,j)-centroid(y,i))
              end do
        
              if (distance<d_min) then
                 d_min=distance
                 i_min=i
              end if
           end do
          !!$OMP END DO
           if( i_min < 0 ) print*," found error by assigning k-index to particle ",j
           indices(j)=i_min
        end do
       
  end subroutine
 subroutine new_centroid(r,n,k,centroid,indices,new_centro,omega)
 integer, intent(in):: n
      real,dimension(:,:),intent(inout),allocatable ::centroid
      real,dimension(:,:),intent(in),allocatable ::r
      integer,dimension(:),intent(in),allocatable::indices
      real,dimension(:,:),intent(out),allocatable:: new_centro
      integer,intent(inout)::k
      integer :: t,y,j,k_ind
      integer,intent(out) :: omega
      real,dimension(:),allocatable :: summ
      allocate(summ(2))
      allocate (new_centro(2,k))
       t=2
      do k_ind=1,k

        omega = count(indices==k_ind)
        summ(1)=0
        summ(2)=0
        do j=1,n
            if (indices(j)==k_ind) then
               summ(1) =+ r(1,j)
               summ(2) =+ r(2,j)
            end if
        end do
      new_centro(1,k_ind) = summ(1)/omega
      new_centro(2,k_ind) = summ(2)/omega
   end do

  
   centroid = new_centro

     !do k_ind=1,k
     !print*, 'new centro',new_centro(:,k_ind)
     !end do

 end subroutine
subroutine costfunction(r,n,k,distancereg,indices,new_centro,cluster,cost)
    integer, dimension (:), allocatable, intent(out)  :: distancereg, indices
    integer, dimension (:), allocatable, intent(out) :: cluster
    real, dimension (:,:), allocatable, intent(in) :: r
    real, dimension (:,:), intent(in), allocatable :: new_centro
    real, dimension(:), intent(out), allocatable :: cost
    integer :: i,k
    allocate(cluster(k))
    allocate(cost(k))
    allocate(distancereg(k))

    call min_distance(r,n,k,centroid,distance,indices,distancereg)
    cluster = 0
    do i=1,k
       cost(i)=0
       cluster(i)=count(indices==i)
       cost(i)=(1.0/cluster(i))*distancereg(i)
      ! print*,cost(i)
    end do

    print*," total sum of cluster members ",sum(cluster)," vs N ",n

 end subroutine

 subroutine convergence_value(converge, centroid, new_centro, cost, cluster)
 real, dimension (:,:), intent(inout), allocatable :: new_centro
 real, dimension (:,:), intent(inout), allocatable :: centroid
 real, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out):: cost
 integer, dimension (:), allocatable, intent(out) :: cluster
 real, dimension(:,:), intent (inout), allocatable:: converge

allocate(converge(2,k))
 call centroid_inits(r, n, k, centroid)
 call min_distance(r, n, k, centroid, distance,indices,distancereg)
 call new_centroid(r,n,k,centroid,indices,new_centro,omega)

 converge = (abs(centroid-new_centro))
 print*, 'this is c',converge
end subroutine

end program read_from_file
```

It runs okay with serial. But I want to apply openmp. I want to each thread doing the same calculation and find which thread have better cost function and time. (all thread doing the clusterization). My attemp and idea is to paralellized the code before encounter the subroutine, that two asterisk. But I do not know if its enough (though I tried it and showing error), and how do make display report of each thread ?
*You might notice from the code that I am a beginner

Comment: It's impossible to locate in this code what you would like to parallelize.

Comment: You already asked about this code and got answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74446687/2044454

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open MP in do nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74446687/open-mp-in-do-nested-loop)

Comment: Hi, yes that answer my previous question. But this one is different

Comment: At some point you cannot just come here with serial codes and ask us to parallelize them for you "because you are a beginner". You say that you have made attempts that do not work: show us the attempt(s) and we will tell you what's wrong and what to do. At some point also you have to learn OpenMP to really understand what you are doing... Here is a quite good course: http://www.idris.fr/media/eng/formations/openmp/idris_openmp_cours-eng-v2.11.pdf (and this contain other resources: http://www.idris.fr/formations/openmp/ ; the page is in french but the resources in english)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I dont actually hope you solve it for me.(It would ve been nice also) but if you show me any guidance/any link to learn. its also enough. Since what I got from internet only this https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/F95_OpenMPv1_v2.pdf . So, thanks

Comment: As I said: show us your attempt(s) that do not work, and then we can tell you what's wrong and how to correct it(them)